# Failure with installation of VSTO Outlook Add-in when path contains "ampersand"

Tags: c#, outlook, path, vsto, ampersand

I have an VSTO-Outlook Add-in, unfortunately I have to release and save this Add-in on a location whose path contains an Ampersand "&"

**Problem**
I can install the plugin from this location (C:\Scripts\Tyne&Wear), the installation works just fine, but when I open outlook where it should "load" the Add-in this failure occurs.: [Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azK67.png) "Value does not fall within the expected range."

**What I've tried:**
I've copied all the files to another location, and installed it there --> everything worked fine
--> so there is definitely an issue with the ampersand in the path
--> I can see in the picture attached "von": there is no ampersand in the path where one should be.

- Checked the deployment dll.manifest for "Ampersands" which are not correctly XMLENCODED "& a m p ;" --> couldn't find anything
- This guy had a similar problem: [Escaping ampersand in a path to Outlook VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54693185/)

  The answer was: "Try to url encode (%26) the ampersand" could this help? -->
  I am sorry but how could this be done?

It drives me mad, I'm grateful for every suggestions or solution which helps me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the ampersand special character is used within the folder structure of the published ClickOnce application the installation and launching will fail. Other special characters such as  : \ / ? * < > are blocked by the operating system. Others such as + ` ; { [ } ] # ! @ # $ % ^ ( ) can be used successfuly however it is always advisable not to use any special characters in either file or folder names.

Read more about that in the [ClickOnce Installation Errors with Message - Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2647493/clickonce-installation-errors-with-message-application-cannot-be-start) article.

Comment: Thank you very much! Not the answer I was hoping for, but should have seen this coming.